# Vue 3 data is not updating after change triggered in methods

Tags: vue.js, shopify, vuejs3

I am trying to understand Vue 3 data management for Shopify Theme. After going through my old code which is based on Vue 2, I cannot update the **data** object by changing value in **methods** function.

Below is the snippet with issue.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],//for NO CONFLICT with liquid theme
  data: () => {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue'
    }
  }, //data ends
  methods: {
    setMessage: (params) => {
      //setting new message
      this.message = params;
      
    }
  }, //methods ends
}).mount('#app1')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app1">
  <h5>${ message }</h5>
  <button v-on:click="setMessage('new message')">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define method like this `setMessage(params) {` not like this `setMessage: (params) => {`